# Python 2.7.3: When starting, can't import _socket

Tags: python

This works fine on another PC. I've reinstalled to no avail. When starting up with python `-v` on both machines, all the imports match except the broken PC imports `t__.py` and `s.py`, and the `import _locale` is in a different place. The file _socket.py exists in the DLLs directory. Any thoughts?

```
>>> import socket
# c:\Python27\Lib\encodings\cp437.pyc matches c:\Python27\Lib\encodings\cp437.py
import encodings.cp437 # precompiled from c:\Python27\Lib\encodings\cp437.pyc
# c:\Python27\Lib\socket.pyc matches c:\Python27\Lib\socket.py
import socket # precompiled from c:\Python27\Lib\socket.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "c:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>> import sys
>>> import pprint
# c:\Python27\Lib\pprint.pyc matches c:\Python27\Lib\pprint.py
import pprint # precompiled from c:\Python27\Lib\pprint.pyc
import cStringIO # builtin
>>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)
['',
 'c:\\Python27',
 'c:\\Python27\\Lib',
 'c:\\Python27\\libs',
 'c:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'c:\\Python27\\Lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
 >>>
```

Comment: Yes. It's stated in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds just like missing dll.

Is _socket.pyd in your python27\DLLs directory? Can you run python.exe directly, then attempt to import _socket? If that works, what does _socket.**file** contain? Do you maybe have 2 pythons on your sys?

If nothing works try to reinstall python.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. The _socket.pyd is in DLLs directory. Have done a reinstall. There are two versions on the machine but there are also two versions on the machine where it works.

Comment: When uninstalling check manually if all files were removed.
Be sure to actually uninstall, clean all remaining s and then install again.